Equation of Motion after Boost
In paper of analyticity and positivity constraints, they take example of effective field of Goldstone boson in a linear sigma model,
$$\mathcal{L}_{\text{eff}} = (\partial{\pi})^2 + \frac{c_3}{\Lambda^4}(\partial_{\mu}\pi\partial^{\mu}\pi)^2+\cdots\tag{2}$$
The equation of motion of fluctuation $\phi = \pi-\pi_0$, where $\pi_0$ is the translational invariant background, $\partial_{\mu}\pi = C_{\mu}$,
$$\left[\eta^{\mu\nu}+4\frac{c_3}{\Lambda^4}C^{\mu}C^{\nu}+\cdots\right]\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi = 0\tag{10}$$
Then if we consider the rest frame $C^{\mu} = (C,0,0,0)$, the e.o.m becomes,
$$\partial_{t}^2\phi-v^2\partial_{i}^2\phi = 0$$
where $v^2 = 1/(1+4c_3C^2/\Lambda^4)\approx 1-4c_3C^2/\Lambda^4$.
Then upon boosting in the $\hat{x}$ direction, $C^{\mu} = (\gamma C, -\gamma\beta C,0,0)$
$$\partial^2\phi + \frac{4c_3}{\Lambda^4}\gamma C\left(\gamma C\partial_{t}^2 + \gamma\beta C\partial_{t}\partial_{x}\phi\right) + \frac{4c_3}{\Lambda^4}(-\gamma\beta C)\left(-\gamma C\partial_{t}\partial_{x}\phi-\gamma\beta C\partial_{x}^2\phi\right) = 0$$
Then
$$\left(1+\frac{4c_3}{\Lambda^4}C^2\gamma^2\right)\partial_{t}^2$\phi + +\frac{4c_3}{\Lambda^4}C^2\cdot2\beta\partial_{t}\partial_{x}\phi-\partial_{\perp}^2\phi - \left(1-\frac{4c_3}{\Lambda^4}C^2\gamma^2\beta^2\right)\partial_{x}^2\phi = 0$$
Identifying $1+4c_3C^2/\Lambda^4 = 1/v^2$ and multiplying $\gamma^2$, one would derive similar equation with a little difference with one in the paper,
$$(1-v^2\beta^2)\partial_{t}^2\phi + 2\beta(1-v^2)\partial_{t}\partial_{x}\phi - (v^2-\beta^2)\partial_{x}^2\phi - v^2(1-\beta^2)\partial_{\perp}^2\phi = 0$$
However, the equation in the paper doesn't have coefficient $(1-\beta^2)$ in the last term, which is very confusing to me, can anyone show me why?
